# "Unknow resource with key" errors when using SonarQube Issues Report Plugin

Tags: sonarqube

I am using SonarQube 4.1 with the Issues Report plugin.
My project is a Java Maven project with multiple module.
When I run incremental analysis from my workstation using the Issues Report plugin using:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.analysis.mode=incremental -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
```

I get many (>20K) warnings from the issues reporter (analysis finishes succesfully).
The warnings are of the format:

```
[WARN] [<time>] Unknow resource with key <com.my.project.name>:<modul1.name>:<com.my.class.name>
```

Can anyone please help me understand the source and meaning of this warning so I can fix it?

Thanks,
Noam

P.S. for the plugin devs out there - we probably want to fix the typo in "Unknow"

Answer (score 0):

Are you using issues-report-plugin version 1.1? Because this version has some fixes to support multi module projects.

It is fixed issues-report-plugin version 1.3, look at 
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARISSRP-7